# MKPolyline displays artifact/pixelation on map after zoom-in

Tags: ios, mapkit

Including a photo below, as I'm not sure how to describe this exactly.

We're using MKPolyline to draw a line on a map in an iOS application. After drawing the line, the user can zoom in or out on the map.

After zooming in, occasionally, the following artifact/pixelation can be seen, usually toward the outer bounds of the line.

[image: MKPolyline]

Any thoughts/suggestions on what is causing this, and how to fix it? Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: I've seen some of the same on close zoom ins, more often on annotation points but also on polylines.  Not sure why / haven't addressed it yet, but you're not alone.

Comment: It's look like this answer do the trick:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601768/mkpolylinerenderer-produces-jagged-unequal-paths

Comment: @AnthonyMarchenko thanks for the link!

Comment: Seems to just happen with iOS 10. Maybe, Apple will fix it in iOS 11...